# Cycling through an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to set up an input method for a user to enter a number of tree seeds for each type of tree. There are three different tree types. I just want to let the user enter the amount for all three in this method that I have created, and if they enter invalid entry(empty string or a string or a number<0) it will shoot an error.

Is my "for" loop appropriate here? I want to increment the amount for both the desiredYield array and the treeTypes array so the values will be parallel. Later in the program I need to calculate the amount of trees that will be required by account for the death of seeds.

Any advice helps.

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class TreeCalc{

     public static void main(String[] args){

      String[] treeTypes = new String[] {"Fir", "Pine", "Spruce"};
      int[] desiredYield = new int [treeTypes.length];
      double[] decayRate = new double[] {0.07, 0.12, 0.08};
      desiredYield[] = getYield();
      getCalculate(decayRate[], treeTypes[], desiredYield[]);
      printMessage();

  }

     //Asks user to input # of trees for each tree type
     public static int getYield(){
        int index= 0;
        do{
           for(int i=0;i<=treeTypes.length;i++){
             try{
             desiredYield[index] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your desired yield for: " +treeTypes[i]));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
           if(desiredYield[index]==("") || desiredYield[index]<0){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for "+treeTypes[i]);
          }else{
              index++
        }
       }
     }
    }while(desiredYield[index]<0 || desiredYield[index]==(""));
   }
  }
```

Comment: Why you are using do - while loop?

Comment: Because I require input validation

Comment: Check my answer if its help you.

Comment: If you are looking for a code review, you should post the code over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, I will post there.

Comment: @hotzst `desiredYield[] = getYield()` makes no sense and won't compile, so the question would be off-topic for Code Review in its current form.

Comment: @200_success what is wrong with that? I am unsure of what I did wrong there. shouldn't it just be desiredYield= getYield(); ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do or what you're asking. The `getYield()` function doesn't have a `return` statement.  `index++` is missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<=treeTypes.length;i++){
             try{
             desiredYield[index] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your desired yield for: " +treeTypes[i]));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
           if(desiredYield[index]==("") || desiredYield[index]<0){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for "+treeTypes[i]);
          }else{
              index++
        }
       }
```

You need to remove '=' from your for loop.

Updated code should be  :

```
for(int i=0;i < treeTypes.length;i++){
             try{
             desiredYield[index] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your desired yield for: " +treeTypes[i]));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
           if(desiredYield[index]==("") || desiredYield[index]<0){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for "+treeTypes[i]);
          }else{
              index++
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much- this is more efficient than what I had. However, I get quite a few compiler errors for the main method.

Comment: I fixed the errors in the main method, my errors in the method are like this: http://puu.sh/ltbq0/cd66c87905.png

Comment: getYield method return only int however desiredYield its a int array, that why you are getting incompatible types.